# Uniform Sampling of the space of unit determinant 2X2 matrices

Tags: matrices, statistics, sampling

Is there a way to algorithmically generate uniformly random determinant=1 matrices such that I have reasonably spanned the entire space of such matrices?

To elaborate more precisely: consider the same question for rotation matrices $R \in SO(2)$. I create $\theta_i = uniformrandom (-\pi/2 , \pi/2)$ and create $R_i = \big{[} \begin{matrix}  cos \theta_i & -sin\theta_i\\sin\theta_i & cos\theta_i \end{matrix} \big{]} $  for i=1,2,...N

Now I know that for larger and larger N, I have spanned SO(2) more and more uniformly denser and that the likelyhood of missing out any "corners"  reduces as I choose larger N. How do I mimic the exact same experiment for unit determinant matrices in general?, i.e. How to uniformly sample the space of unit determinant 2X2 matrices?,   The "uniform" is essential :)

Comment: I think that it won't be possible to get a uniform distribution in the same way because the set of determinant-1 matrices is not *compact* (that is, it's not bounded).

Comment: Even if you were restricted to diagonal unit determinant $2\times2$ matrices  where the magnitude of the diagonal values were less than or equal to $2$, i.e. $\left( \begin{matrix}  a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{matrix} \right)$ with $|a| \le 2$ and $|d| \le 2$ and $ad=1$, it is not immediately obvious to me how you would select from these *uniformly*

Comment: @henry: since I have a parameterization of the matrix (i.e. for every $a$, I have a, $D(a)$ where, $D = \big{[} \begin{matrix}  a&0\\0&1/a \end{matrix} \big{]}$ would'nt uniform($a\in [-2,2] - {0} $) be OK?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom , I agree, but is there a way to parameterize the space of such matrices....so like henry mentioned, If there is a way to say that for all unit determinant matrices with constraints on the norm.....can I achieve a parametrization? (which I will uniformly sample)

Comment: Apologies, $1/a$  is not uniform....@henry you are right, so any suggestive strategies ? As mentioned, since it is not compact, I am looking to constrain the space somehow and say that it is uniform in a particular region, say by bounding the norm or something....

Comment: My suggestion: Choose $A_1,B_1,C_1,D_1$ from some distribution symmetric about zero.  Divide them all by $\sqrt{|A_1D_1-B_1C_1|}$ to give $A_2,B_2,C_2,D_2$ with determinant $\pm1$ and if that gives a determinant of $-1$ then multiply $A_2$ and $B_2$ by $-1$.  This may  not be uniform in a meaningful sense, though all four components should be identically distributed (which depends on the original distribution).